# How can I Implement Zend Framework 3 + Ajax Pagination?

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, pagination, doctrine, zend-framework3

Does anyone know how to implement *Ajax Pagination* with **Zend Framework 3** (zf3)?

I used Doctrine ORM to retrieve data from database.

Comment: Please add more information on the steps you took and where you failed. If you use a manual refer to it. And if you deviate from it mention what an here you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. The same as a normal GET request really, only will you respond dynamically because it concerns an `xml http request`.

Take, for example, the following `indexAction`

```
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

// class, other use-statements, etc

public function indexAction()
{
    $page = $this->params()->fromQuery('page', 1); // get page from GET, default page 1

    /** @var QueryBuilder $qb */
    $qb = $this->getObjectManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('u')
       ->from(User::class, 'u')
       ->orderBy('u.createdAt', 'DESC');

    $paginator = new Paginator(new OrmAdapter(new OrmPaginator($qb)));
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(25);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return new JsonModel([
            'paginator'   => $paginator,
            'queryParams' => $this->params()->fromQuery(),
        ]);
    }
    return [
        'paginator'   => $paginator,
        'queryParams' => $this->params()->fromQuery(),
    ];
}
```

Here you would normally end up at the bottom most `return` statement for a standard GET request. In case of an ajax type request, the statement `$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()` returns `true` and you know it's something send via, let's say `$.ajax / $.get / $.post` (usually, unless native JS or something similar). In these cases you want to respond with just the data, not a completely rendered views. This is when you return the `JsonModel`.

To make sure it works as intended, you must also have the `JsonViewStrategy` enabled in your configuration. You might wish to enable this in your `global.php` instead of just a module, like below, to enable it everywhere:

```
'view_manager' => [
    //...

    'strategies' => [
        'ViewJsonStrategy',
    ],
],
```

The only things left to do, then, are client-side things with JavaScript. Like making sure you update the pagination, page contents, etc. Maybe a URI anchor...